# enableBrowserColor() on $mdThemingProvider in Angular-Material throwing error

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, meta-tags

I'm trying to change the browser color with .enableBrowserColor() but it keeps showing error.

[image]

My code is

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
                .accentPalette('red')
                .enableBrowserColor({
                  theme: 'default',
                  palette: 'primary',
                  hue: '800'
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do it in that way. To fix this problem you have to do a workaround like this:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
  .accentPalette('red');

// Mobile browsers status bar color
$mdThemingProvider.enableBrowserColor({
    theme: 'defualt',
    palette: 'blue-grey',      // <-- Note this, you have to use a predefined palette name
    hue: '800'
});
```

Here you can find the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/01_introduction) containing some useful tips and info.
I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank You , i understood the concept but Its showing the same error : TypeError: $mdThemingProvider.enableBrowserColor is not a function

Comment: @AmitSingh I took the block of code from a site i'm developing and there it works fine... Can you post your configuration code part and the part where you declare your module?

Comment: `(function() {
    angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons', 'ng-fx', 'ngAnimate'])
            .config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
                .accentPalette('red') enableBrowserColor({
                    theme: 'defualt',
                    palette: 'blue-grey',
                    hue: '800'
                });
        }])
}());`

Comment: @AmitSingh Here there is the code you posted and modified to work. You have simply to add `$mdThemingProvider` before `.enableBrowserColor`. So it become `(function() { 
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) { 
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default') 
        .primaryPalette('blue-grey') 
        .accentPalette('red') 
        
        $mdThemingProvider.enableBrowserColor({ 
                theme: 'defualt', 
                palette: 'blue-grey', 
                hue: '800' 
        }); 
    }]) 
}());`